# Setting -TargetMigration with EF core

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to target a previous applied migration using `dotnet ef -TargetMigration: {MigrationName}`

getting below error

> Unrecognized option '-TargetMigration:0'

Is this command has been removed in Entity Framework Core?  Is there any alternative for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use as shown below on the `package manager console` :

```
 PM > Update-Database [[-Migration] <String>]
```

**Parameter :**

```
-Migration <String>
```

- Specifies the target migration.
- If '0', all migrations will be reverted.
- If omitted, all pending migrations will be applied.

Comment: this only works from with in VS.NET on the Package Management Console.

Comment: I have a feeling that he isn't using VS.NET :(

Comment: I am using `.net core` project. I cannot use Package manager for that as i have a separate class library for datacontext.

Comment: if you're using `VS` then you can select your `CL` within `PMC` no ? what is the issue there ?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html

Remember its totally different from what you expect...

`dotnet ef migrations list
dotnet ef migrations [arg] {option}`

`dotnet ef migrations add [name]`

`"      "    "        remove` //removes last

as per the instructions manually removing the changes from the database if it has been applied already. e.g `dotnet ef database update`.

Comment: When i run this i am getting `Unrecognized command or argument 'migration'`

Comment: It should be migration**s**

Comment: It's not working. I think the only allowed commands for `migrations` are `add`, `list`, `remove`, `script`.   If i run you command. It is not recognizing `migrationname` and throwing unrecognized command error.

Comment: remember the CLI dotnet commands are slight different from the PMC commands